# Error in assignment of useState variable react

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

i have a promise with a param than is an id of a movie, but in the moment i tried to assign that in the useEffect response dont assign any value

(sorry for bad english)

```
   //promise
export const getMovieDetails = (numero) => {     //numero is the movie id
    return fetch(`${BASE_URL}/movie/${numero}?api_key=${API_KEY}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
}



 useEffect(() => {
        backgroundMovie && getMovieDetails(backgroundMovie?.id) *//here you give backgroundMovie.id like the param of the promise*
        .then((response) => {
            setMovieDetails(response.results); //the error is here
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error: ", error);
        });
    }, [backgroundMovie,getMovieDetails]);


// i didn't know why this is happen
```

Comment: Is getMovieDetails getting fired? What value has responsee?

Comment: the response has the promise. the problem is that for some reason setMmovieDetails doesnt assign that value to movieDetails (that is the variable of the useState)

Comment: Do you mean that `response.results` is not undefined or an empty string? If yes, can you please provide more of the source component code? Side note: the only existing parameter of a Promise is an executor for its constructor, but this can not be its resolved data, therefore I think that when writing *I have a promise with a param that is an id*, you mean *I have a function that takes an id and returns a promise*, right?

Comment: i mean i have a promise with a parameter, i pass to the promise an id of a movie trought that param, the response of that pass to the useEffect and its suposed to assign that value (an array) to the variable of the useState

Comment: the problem is the value is not assigned to the movieDetails variable       useEffect(() => {
        
        backgroundMovie && getMovieDetails(backgroundMovie?.id)
        
        .then((response) => {
            
            setMovieDetails(response.results);
            console.log(response)        
           
            
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error: ", error);
        });
    }, [backgroundMovie,getMovieDetails]); //wait for the promise and for the state of backgroundMovie

Comment: background movie has te entire array that is passed to  the promise (getMovieDetails).  maybe its a litle bit confuse

Answer (score 0):

Try  to change the `getMovieDetails()` `async` so that it will return a promise by returning `await fetch(...)`

```
   //promise
export const getMovieDetails = async (numero) => {     //numero is the movie id
    return await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/movie/${numero}?api_key=${API_KEY}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
}
```

Comment: the promise work but setMovieDetails doesnt assign that value to movieDetails, than is the variable of useState, maybe you need more code

Comment: const [ movieDetails, setMovieDetails ] = useState ([]) that is the useState

Comment: undefined, response didnt pass to movieDetails

Answer (score -1):

mi tutor helps me, and we do it, it wasn't an error of the useEffect only, now the Netflix clon is working, thanks for your answers and for helping the community, i should provide more info in next problems.